# How to deploy a BPMN created in Eclipse as an Activiti project in Alfresco Community v5.1.0

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share

I have Alfresco Community v5.1 installed on my machine locally and have created a **BPMN** model in Eclipse using the **Activiti project** plugin, I have the BPMN and other xml files, but I do not know how to deploy the same in Alfresco Community V5.1.0.

**Files that I have created:**

1. The BPMN file
2. activiti-model.xml
3. content-model.xml
4. model-context.xml
5. share-config-custom.xml

Where do I paste or update these files in the Alfresco Community installed locally and what are the clear steps to deploy the newly created workflow into the Alfresco Community.

I have followed this tutorial by Jeff Pots:
http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-workflow/advanced-workflow-article-2ed.pdf
but, was not able to deploy, please help me find this.

**Alfresco Version:**

Alfresco Share v5.1.f (r125711-b6, Aikau 1.0.63, Spring Surf 5.1.f, Spring WebScripts 6.5, Freemarker 2.3.20-alfresco-patched, Rhino 1.7R4-alfresco-patched, Yui 2.9.0-alfresco-20141223)

**Alfresco Community v5.1.0 (r127059-b7) schema 10001**

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Deploy in Alfresco goes throu AMPs or JARs packages. Try to run first tutorial from jpotts https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html.
You need run Alfresco SDK, create changes, build packages and then deploy them on server (locally or remote). Its not so simple as replacing some files... If you working with old Alfresco 5.1, use old SDK 3.0 and old version of tutorial. If you started with sixth tutorial in Alfresco, it is normal to get lost.

Comment: Hi @David Dejmal, I've tried following this tutorial before, but was not able to get it working. I'll try doing the same once again. Thank you, Sorry for the late reply